# Vulnerable to SQL injections

Tags: security, sql-injection

I'm doing a project to find vulnerable code. Is this code snippet vulnerable to SQL injection?

```
if(ISSET ($_POST['login'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `username` = '$username' && `password` = '$password'") or die(mysqli_error());
```

Comment: Yes. Meet [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: Its PHP. Sorry should of mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Better use the parameterized query mode of Mysqli.

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset ($_POST['pass'])) {

        $user = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['user']),
        $pass = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['pass']);
        $conn = new mysqli("$db_host", "$db_user", "$db_pass", "$db");
        $sql = "select * from admin where username=? and password=?";
        $cmd = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $cmd->bind_param("ss", $user, $pass);
        $cmd->execute();
         ......
         ......
    else {
        echo "Username and password cant not be null !";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Mistakes in your answer: Mixing functions from `mysql` extension and `mysqli` extension. Also escaping inputs is redundant when using parameters. Also storing passwords in plaintext, although that's based on the OP's post. Anyway, this code isn't a good example to follow.